# simple use of fitVids not working?

Tags: jquery, html, css, fitvids

I'm trying to get fitvids to resize my video to fill the parent area as much as it can.  Here's my fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/9513/

code:

```
$(".video-content").fitVids();
```

html:

```
<div class='liveExample'>

    <div class='video-content'>
        <iframe width="200" height="113" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/r65FgUYdBOc?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

    </div>
</div>
```

Any idea why it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Any idea why it's not working?`

You just forgot to include jQuery in your Fiddle (under Frameworks & Extensions)

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/9531/

Comment: This is the correct answer for the OP's question. However if you are bashing your head against the wall trying to figure this out like I was, don't forget to check to make sure that you have `.fitVids()` with camelCase, not `fitvids()`.